# How to setup a case-insensitive regex in regex-urlfilter for Nutch 1.7

Tags: regex, web-crawler, nutch

I need to filter urls based on user input, but the filter must not be case sensitive. 
For example my user wants to filter for files ending with Sewer.pdf. 
If I create a regex like this:

```
+Sewer\.pdf$
```

works fine, however user may have entered SEWER.PDF and it will skip the file.
My solution was to create a rule like this:

```
+[Ss][Ee][Ww][Ee][Rr]\.[Pp][Dd][Ff]
```

However it looks like there should be something like the /i in the regex that would make it much easier.

Does anyone know how to do it in a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try adding the case insensitive flag `(?i)`:

```
.*(?i)SEWER\.PDF
```

Comment: Humm, nope, it has not downloaded Sewer.pdf :(

Comment: try adding the `.*` to the front.

Comment: Works! actually it works without the .*, my actual file is Sewer2008.pdf, but i have not added the 2008 when i tried the first time. So both would worK: +.*(?i)SEWER\.PDF  or +(?i)SEWER\.PDF